# How to excute map reduce on map reduce result in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

i want to know whether i can excute map reduce on a result of map reduce function previous like pipeline without write it on a collection, thanks all. My english is bad, hope you understand my question :(

Comment: [Perform Incremental Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/#perform-incremental-map-reduce) tutorial may be close but writes results to an output collection. I think you could use the same concept to run the initial mapReduce command on the current collection then run the subsequent mapReduce operation on the output collection?

Answer (score 1):

Chaining of map reduce is not supported at this time without storing intermediary data in some kind of collection.

Again map reduce in MongoDB is not very efficient and MongoDB recommend to export data  and run map reduce in proper framework like Hadoop if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this could cost you a lot of performance, you have to store the first result in a new colllection, then run next map-reduce on the previous output collection. See [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#output-to-a-collection) for more infomation.

However, you still can pipeline query results through aggregation pipeline, see [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-expressions). So consider convert your map-reduce to aggregation.